# Reverse Geocoding with Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on the JavaScript Google Map API (Version3) and more precisely on the reverse geolocation. With the help of [the official documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding), I successed to perform the reverse geocoding, I found the address corresponding to the latitude and longitude coordonates.
But I can't find how to reach the name bound to the address. Is it possible? How can it be performed?

Thanks you.
Camille.

Comment: name of what? please provide an example.

Comment: For example, I submit to the Google Map API the coordonates "46.1124, 1.245", afterwards it returns the address associates. I would like  the API gives me the name of the shop or whatever at this address. Is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean trying to extract info from the return result?

Answer (score 3):

You really need to loop and do multiple checks of what google found at these points a small script to actually reads/loop the returned data would be (in PHP):

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=46.1124,1.245&sensor=true"));
if($data->status == "OK") {
    if(count($data->results)) {
        foreach($data->results as $result) {
            echo $result->formatted_address . "<br />";
        }
    }
} else {
    // error
}
?>
```

Now based on the documentation:

> Note that the reverse geocoder
>   returned more than one result. ...etc

And:

> Generally, addresses are returned from
>   most specific to least specific; the
>   more exact address is the most
>   prominent result...etc

You only need the first result to get what you want (or at least to search for it there `$data->results[0]->`.
So have a read of the [types](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types) and based on that you can check if the result you want present or not:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=46.1124,1.245&sensor=true"));
if($data->status == "OK") {
    if(count($data->results)) {
        foreach($data->results[0]->address_components as $component) {
            if(in_array("premise",$component->types) || in_array("route",$component->types) || in_array("park",$component->types)) {
                echo $component->long_name . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    // error
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I will try your solution ifaour. Cheers

Comment: just wondering why this was a PHP solution and not a JS solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google Map API has a Beta release version of a place lookup API. I think this is what your looking for. Basically, you pass a lat/lng or address and google does a reverse lookup of the address to a place name (if its in its database).

See their documentation at:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Excerpt from their intro on Places API:

The Places API has two basic types of requests, which are related: Place Search requests and Place Details requests. A Place Search request initiates a request for "places" around a provided location, often provided via geolocation (so that a user can search for the Place they are currently located or Places nearby). The Places API returns a list of candidate places that are near the provided location and the user can then initiate a Place Details request on a specific entity returned in the original search.