# How do I convert Lat and Long to a facility name in Google Maps?

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have lat and long coordinates and I want to convert them to the facility name or place name that is listed on google maps (or at least the closest facility).
I am not trying to plot anything on a map, I am just looking for the facility name.  In the example below originally posted here> [Reverse Geocoding with Google Map API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874556/reverse-geocoding-with-google-map-api) by [ifaour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337227/ifaour), that I am using, it is returning the street name and I am not sure how to return the place name.  I have tried using "premise" as per google maps api but I am not too familiar with the sytnax as I am a beginner.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=43.97513954,-78.1601639&sensor=true&radius=300"));
if($data->status == "OK") {
if(count($data->results)) {
    foreach($data->results[0]->address_components as $component) {
        if(in_array("premise",$component->types) || in_array("colloquial_area",$component->types) || in_array("route",$component->types) || in_array("park",$component->types)) {
            echo $component->long_name . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
} else {
// error
}
?>
```

I am trying to get the co-ordinates to return "Cobourg Community Center" but it returns "D'Arcy Street" instead.

It would be great to pull the closest name within 300meters too.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: The geocoder returns addresses.  If you want a "place name", you probably need to use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)

Comment: I was looking into that too, but I cannot find any examples that use "premise"

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxC.html?q=Cobourg%20Community%20Center

Comment: ya, thats pretty much what I am a looking for... how do I minimize the code so its just "Cobourg Community Center"  from a lat and long?

Comment: I read the code and it is searching based on the name of the facility and I need it to search based on lat and long coordinates and return the facility name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many hours of testing research it turns out that this code *actually* works as intended.  The fault is that the facilities are not actually tagged as a "premise" by Google, which is why the names are not being returned.  I tested with lat and long from a known Google "premise" and it worked correctly.  Thank you for all suggestions.  I will now need to post a new question based on Google Maps "nearby" functionality